# Go algorithm for hour convertion not converting correctly

Tags: algorithm, go, debugging

I've come across a HackerRank challenge where I should build a function which takes a string in a given format of the time in the 12-hour format to the 24-hour format.

I managed to do that with the code below, but as you can notice, there's a special case for the 09 pm. Whenever I'd type in an hour starting with 09 (only this damn one) it'd convert the 09 to 12. So I had to actually create a specific case to treat that, which worked, but I'd like to understand why it happened. Do you know what the problem may be?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Conversion struct {
    conversion string
}

func timeConversion(s string) string {
    var conversion Conversion
    firstValue := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", string(s[0]), string(s[1]))
    secondValue := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", string(s[3]), string(s[4]))
    firstValueNumber, _ := strconv.ParseInt(firstValue, 0, 16)

    fmt.Print()

    if strings.Contains(s, "A") {
        if firstValue == "12" {
            conversion.conversion = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s:%s%s", "00", secondValue, string(s[len(s)-4]), string(s[len(s)-3]))
        } else {
            conversion.conversion = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s:%s%s", firstValue, secondValue, string(s[len(s)-4]), string(s[len(s)-3]))
        }
    } else if strings.Contains(s, "P") {
        if firstValue == "12" {
            conversion.conversion = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s:%s%s", "12", secondValue, string(s[len(s)-4]), string(s[len(s)-3]))
        } else if firstValue == "09" {
            conversion.conversion = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s:%s%s", "21", secondValue, string(s[len(s)-4]), string(s[len(s)-3]))
        } else {
            conversion.conversion = fmt.Sprintf("%d:%s:%s%s", firstValueNumber+12, secondValue, string(s[len(s)-4]), string(s[len(s)-3]))
        }
    }

    return conversion.conversion
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print(timeConversion("09:08:23PM"))
}
```

Comment: Always start of by removing unnecessary stuff (everything that is not there cannot cause problems) `firstValue = s[:2]`, same for second value. Then always handle errors! Simplify code, use the right function, don't try to go fancy:Simple string to int is done with strconv.Atoi, not ParseInt. Remember to _always_ read the whole documentation of _any_ function you use (don't guess).

Comment: Never ignore errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you catch the error during your string to int conversion, you'll notice that for values `>7`, the conversion fails

```
firstValueNumber, err := strconv.ParseInt(firstValue, 0, 64)
if err != nil {
     fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
}
// "08" results in invalid syntaxfirstValueNumber being printed
```

It happens because you pass 0 as the base, telling `parseInt` to infer the base from the first character of the string. A leading `'0'` implies octal base, and so digits greater than 7 would be invalid. Pass 10 instead and you won't need special handling.